# Prevent Firebird from printing queries in Visual Studio debug output window

Tags: visual-studio, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

We have newly adopted Firebird in our project, using it via Entity Framework. I now noticed that Firebird prints every query to Visual Studio's debug output window. Here's a simplified example:

```
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient Information: 0 : Command:
SELECT 
"B"."FOO" AS "FOO" 
FROM "BAR" AS "B"
WHERE [...]
Parameters:
Name:p__linq__0 Type:TimeStamp  Used Value:19.03.2020 07:57:59
Name:p__linq__1 Type:Guid   Used Value:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

With the old DBMS we didn't have such output, so I don't think that some generic Entity Framework feature is at work here. I am aware of `DbContext.Database.Log`, but I doublechecked that we don't use this in our code base.

I verified that it's not our logging framework (log4net) that redirects something to the VS debug output. Our app.config also does not contain anything that looks suspicious. Last but not least, an internet search didn't yield anything useful.

So I am really at a loss here. Do you know where this output comes from, and how I can disable it?

We use Visual Studio 2019 and Firebird 3.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that exhibits the behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your `app.config` and add this code:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient">
        <listeners>
          <clear />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Now [no diagnostics listener is configured](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/232603-improved-command-logging-in-ado-net-provider-for-firebird-part-2) and you get no output.